# Custom Email Header and Footer Template in Magento 2

Tags: email-templates, luma-theme, magento-2.1.7

How can I change the email header template

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
```

or footer template

```
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can override these templates in your custom theme and edit the html as per your requirement.

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Email/email/header.html
app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Email/email/footer.html
```

Comment: it worked like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 12):

You can override your core header and footer template into your theme folder,

```
vendor/magento/module-email/view/frontend/email/header.html
```

To your theme,

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{thememane}/Magento_Email/email/header.html
```

Same Process for Footer.html file.

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{thememane}/Magento_Email/email/footer.html
```

Run

```
php magento setup:upgrade
php magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Clear cache.

Comment: Grazie per la risposta il mio percorso è / public_html / app / design / frontend / Magento / luma   
I have to create the folders / public_html / app / design / frontend / Vendor / luma / Magento_Email / email / header.html and footer.html

Comment: Adminhtml custom email template not set header footer. Can you please. @Rakesh Sir

Answer (score 6):

This setting available in:

> Content -> Configuration -> Default Store View -> Transactional Emails

Answer (score 2):

In Magento 2.3.5 you can set it here:
Content -> Design -> Configuration --> /YOUR STORE/ --> Transactional emails